# Java Spring add Transitional property to Projector

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a projector interface class that I want to add a transitional property to.

The projector

```
public interface CourseInfo  {
    ...
    CoursePermission setCoursePermission(CoursePermission permission);
    CoursePermission getCoursePermission();
}
```

The Class

```
import javax.persistence.Transient

public class Course extends BaseModel {
  ....
@Transient
public CoursePermission permission;
}
```

And then later I want to be able to set this transient property before sending to client

```
 course.setCoursePermission(permission);
```

The error I get is:

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
 [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
 A TupleBackedMap cannot be modified.] with root cause

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: A TupleBackedMap cannot be modified.
```

Am I doing this the right way? Is it even possible?